# Is it safe to delete an image after creating it with gs and displaying it this way in php?

Tags: php, delete-file

EDIT 2
I moved the gs to the image php script. Now the file is created there and then deleted so there is no chance that a file will be left on the disk. The problem I had was that bots would read the main file without calling the image script thus the image file was not deleted. With the  gs command in the image script, it works as it should. I just pass the file name and page number to the image script.

---

I am creating a png image from a pdf

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r600 -dDownScaleFactor=3 -dFirstPage=11 -dLastPage=11 -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="xyzzy.png" myPDF.pdf
```

Then I display it and call a php image file that deletes the image after a delay

```
<img src='xyzzy_png'>
<img src="delete_img.php" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt="">
```

delete_img.php looks like this

```
 <?header('Content-type:image/png');
 include("php8sucks.php");
 $key = get_num('n');
 $file = 'xyzzy' . $key . '.png';
 readfile($file);
 usleep(100000);
 unlink($file);
 exit;
 ?>
```

Is this safe? How can it fail? I have tested it and can see the file come and go on my server. Even if I close the main file, after the sleep time the image file is removed.

I should add, I tried several other suggestions on SO that did not work. There are others I have not tried that involve having some script that does house cleaning periodically. That would probably work but I worry about a bot loading a huge number of files and overloading the server space. I would rather clean up as I go.

The situation I am in is that there are lots of potential files for all the possible pdf conversions and I need to increase the resolution. That would just use too much server space so I can't leave all the potential files lying around.

What other conditions should I test? Anything I am overlooking?

What is a safe delay? I have tested 5 seconds and 60 seconds. Both seem to work. I have not tested multiple versions of my delete_img.php file running but of course I would use different file names for different files.

I will note that including the delete_img.php file rather than calling it does not work. This is the only way I could think of calling the file without including it. The zero size image does not show up on in Chrome or Firefox. I have not tried other browsers.

I clearly need to make sure the delete_img.php file cannot delete any old file on my server. It is hard coded for testing but eventually it would have some kind of safety to only delete specific files. I am thinking file names like 'filennnn.png where the nnnn is a random number and it the only thing passed to the delete_img.php file.

=====EDIT=============
The suggested solution isn't working. The files display just fine but the original image is not being deleted. The call to this function is a 10 digit random number defining the file. That way there can't be any conflicts with two users getting the same filename.

I implemented the delete_img.php funtion like this

```
<?header('Content-type:image/png');
include("php8sucks.php");
$file = get_num('n');
$file2 = 'xyzzy' . $file . '.png';
readfile($file2);
unlink($file2);
exit;
?>
```

php8sucks has this function in it

```
function get_num($num){
    if(isset($_GET[$num])){
        $s = val_num($_GET[$num]);
    }   
    else $s = 0;
    return $s;
}
```

I am not sure what it going on. I will see if a delay will help. Perhaps it is a timing issue. For now, I will delete the files manually. Perhaps I will end up with a cron job afterall.

Comment: `<?header("Content-type: image/png");` should be `<?php header("Content-type: image/png");`

Comment: "safe" in what way? Do you mean to avoid the possibility of the image being deleted before it's been served to the browser? If you're worried, have a cron job which sweeps up older image files nightly or something like that.

Comment: Who calls the `gs` command? Is the `xyzzy_png` page or something else?

Comment: The main page that will display the target page from the myPDF file. It calls the gs through an exec command. The gs script generates the xyzzy.png temporary file which is displayed and then deleted.

Comment: In that case the most robust solution would be to inline the image into the `img` tag, otherwise you could run into all kind of corner cases, like two users requesting the main page at very close times and only one of the receiving the image because it got deleted meanwhile.

Comment: I am glad you asked that. It caused me to check my server and it had 668 undeleted files. Each file has a 10 digit random number in it like xyzzy8360861285.png so the case you bring up can't happen. But the files are not being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep(5)` makes it unlikely to fail. But a better way would be to use a single script to fetch the image and delete it.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile('xyzzy.png');
unlink('xyzzy.png');
```

You should also move the image file out of the web root, so it can only be fetched through the script that deletes it.

Comment: I tested this and it works! Thank you. Can you tell me what about readfile allows the image to be displayed before it is deleted? Is there a potential race or is this guaranteed to work?  Also, can you expand on the comment about moving the file? Are you saying move it or just don't put it in the root file to begin with?

Comment: There's no race. `readfile()` is a synchronous function that simply copies the contents of the file to standard output.

Comment: I'm saying don't put it in the root to begin with. That way users won't be able to bypass the script to download the image directly.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. Your delete_img.php script copies the image, deletes it, and then returns the copy to the calling program where it is then displayed. I found out that if I displayed the image before the call to the delete script, I ended up with two copies assuming I didn't size it to 0.

Comment: You don't need the hidden pixel with this. Just one image.

Comment: Thank you. Really nice solution to this problem.

Comment: The files are not being deleted. I will add some code to the question to clarify what I am seeing.

Comment: Make sure the webserver userid has permission to delete files in the directory. Other than that, I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Check your error log to see if `unlink()` is getting an error.

Comment: The only errors in the log are from a variable I forgot to define and none since I fixed that. In terms of the webserver, it was working fine in my testing here at home. The only thing I can think of is that I have gigabit fiber and maybe users have slower connections but I don't see how that could be a factor.

Comment: Connection speed is irrelevant, this is all happening on the server.

Comment: If you put `error_log("before unlink $file2");` and `error_log("after unlink $file2");` around the `unlink()` call, do you see those in the log?

Comment: This is most strange. I do see the pair of before and after along with another I put in before the read file. But the files that are logged are in fact deleted but most of the files show that are not deleted don't show up in the log.  That must mean that the files are being created but not shown, Something is running the main file but not loading the image. Probably bots. I get a lot of bots. I had not considered that.

Comment: This is why the files should be outside the webroot, so they can only be accessed through the script.

Comment: What I need to do is put the entire creation of the image into the php image file. Then if it isn't called, there will be no file created. If it is called, then your method will delete it.

Comment: If you're creating the image dynamically in the script, you don't need to put it in a file at all. Then there's nothing to delete.

Comment: So I just specify sOutputFile=- and return. Thanks once more.

Comment: I don't know what `sOutputFile=` refers to.

Comment: That is apparently how you get gs to write to the standard output instead of to a file. I have not tried it yet. This way I don't need to create a file with gs. I am working on encrypting the pdf location so I can pass that to the php image script.

Comment: I could not get gs to work with the sOutputFile=- and since someone removed ghostscript as one of my key words there is no help on that one. But I did create a temp file in the new image script using gs and then did the readfile, unlink thing in that file and that is working without filling the disk with temp files. Each file has a unique name do there is no possibility of a collision.

Comment: Sorry about that, I never actually read the beginning of the script where you described how you were creating the files.

Comment: It is working great now. I could not have done it without your assistance. I have marked this as the solution because it solves the question asked. I added an edit to explain what I did to deal with the bot problem. Thanks again.